# Search for file in folder1 and execute a script if that file isn't in folder2

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep, find

`folder1` contains only `.flv` files.

`folder2` contains only `.mp4` files.

All `.flv` files in `folder1` SHOULD have a corresponding file ending in `.mp4` in `folder2` :

`/folder1/123.flv` and `/folder2/123.mp4`.

I need a script that will find any `.flv`'s that are missing a `.mp4` and execute a script that will run mencoder to create the corresponding `.mp4`.  I've done my best, this is what I've come up with but am stuck with the IF THEN statements.

```
for i in `find /folder1 -type f -iname '*.flv' -printf "%f\n" | 
    sed 's/.flv//g'` ; do 
    if [[ -n $(find /folder2/$i.mp4 -exec grep \-q 0 {} \;) ]] then
        /scripts/script.sh $i  fi ; done
```

The bash script needs to be executed like so:

```
/scripts/script.sh $i
```

so the filename without any extension.

Comment: looks like you have a semi-colon (or a newline) missing before the `then` and the `fi`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
find folder1 -type f -iname '*.flv' -exec bash -c \
    'f=${1#folder1/}; [ -f "folder2/${f%.flv}.mp4" ] || 
     scripts/script.sh "${1%.flv}"' none {} \;
```

This will work file's whose names contain whitespace or other difficult characters.

#### How it works

- `find folder1 -type f -iname '*.flv'`

  This finds the flv files
- `-exec bash -c '...'`

  For every flv file found this tells find to run bash which runs the script in quotes (see below).
- `f=${1#folder1/}`

  This creates a variable `f` which has the name of the flv file without the leading directory.
- `[ -f "folder2/${f%.flv}.mp4" ]`

  This tests to see whether a corresponding mp4 file exists.
- `||`

  This tells bash to execute the command which follows only if the preceding command returned false (in other words, if no such mp4 file was found).
- `scripts/script.sh "${1%.flv}"'`

  This runs your script on those flv files that are missing mp4 files.  The files are supplied to `script.sh` with the `.flv` part removed.
- `none {}`

  This tells bash to assign the string `none` to `$0` (this placeholder is never used) and to assign the name of the file found by `find`, denoted `{}`, to shell variable `$1`.
- `\;`

  This signals the end of the find's `-exec` command.

Comment: Do you get paid to do this, because you should.  Thanks a million